# Writing domains with coded values in ArcSDE Enterprise Geodatabase

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, domains, error-000800

I'm trying to write a new domain and values in our ArcSDE database but I receive the following error:

Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 34, in    File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 1317, in AddCodedValueToDomain     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000800: The value is not a member of Gas Service Diameter Plastic PVC | Rectifier Manufacturer | Work Order Status | GasASTMF2897CSteelPipeType | Pipe Diameter Plastic PVC | Leak Survey Frequency..

Line 34) arcpy.AddCodedValueToDomain_management(gdb, domName, code, domDict[code])

Notes: The domain name is successfully created in the enterprise geodatabase but the coded values return an error.

**Current ArcSDE Enterprise Geodatabase Version: 10.3.1.**

Code:

```
#Import system modules
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Users/jnmiller/AppData/Roaming/ESRI/Desktop10.3/ArcCatalog"

# Set local parameters
domName = "test123"
gdb = "GIS.sde"


# Process: Create the coded value domain
arcpy.CreateDomain_management(gdb, domName, "Description", "TEXT", "CODED")


# List of domain values in load order
domainList = ["1"]

# Store all the domain values in a dictionary with the domain code as the "key" and the
# domain description as the "value" (domDict[code])

domDict = {"1":"test 1"}


# Process: Add valid material types to the domain
# use a for loop to cycle through all the domain codes in the dictionary
for code in domainList:
    arcpy.AddCodedValueToDomain_management(gdb, domName, code, domDict[code])

print "Finished!"
```

Comment: Instead of using domainList can't you just loop through the domDict instead: for code in domDict:

Comment: @Dowlers I just tried what you suggested but it's still giving me the following error with arcpy.AddCodedValueToDomain_management(gdb, domName, code, domDict[code])                                                                                            
Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 29, in <module>   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 1317, in AddCodedValueToDomain     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000800: The value is not a member of Gas Service Diameter Plastic PVC | Rectifier Manufacturer

Comment: Where is it finding the existing values Gas Service Diameter Plastic PVC | Rectifier Manufacturer...etc? Might the domain already exist? Can you domName to something new?

Comment: Also if the domain already exists I think only the owner can change it.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance your python code has bad syntax. The for iteration should be indented like this:

```
for code in domainList:
    arcpy.AddCodedValueToDomain_management(gdb, domName, code, domDict[code])
```

Another error looks to be that you are calling a dictionary key which does not exist. domDict[code] will return nothing since the value "1" is not in your domainList.

Comment: I edited my code above with the correct syntax. The error is still valid while trying to add coded values.